# Visual Studio 2005 build problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, build

Cheers,

I have Microsoft VS 2005 installed (full version). And when I'm trying to build or debug my solution (with 10 projects) a windows installer window opens and says:

The feature you are trying to use is on cd-rom or other removable....

So I then put my VS2005 CD and VS does his thing and than my build and debug processes are working. But when I shut down VS and open it again and when I want again to build my solution it asks me the same thing.

I deleted VS2005 and installed it again (again full version) and it asks me the same thing. I am really crazy right now.. why VS just don't do "update" or something, I don't want to insert CD every time I start VS.

tnx

Comment: what is it installing everytime you startup?

Comment: It doesn't says anything.

Just this window:  http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/6023/87077118.jpg

and when I insert my VS2005 it just does it's thing and then build and debug are working normally (but CD must be in CD-ROM). It seems that VS doesn't update but it just uses resources from CD.. I think it's stupid.

Comment: Do you customize the installation in any way?

Answer (score 1):

When Visual Studio was installed on your system, you might have chosen a typical installation or a custom installation that did not include everything available to it. This is appropriate in some cases (low disk space, you know only a certain subset is all that is aver or should ever be used).

Try reinstalling, and make sure its a complete install. And don't have it delete unused pieces.